# Activiti Escalation Listener Configuration

Tags: spring, activiti

I am using activiti 5.18.

Behind the scenes : There are few task which are getting routed though a workflow. Some of these tasks are eligible for escalation. I have written my escalation listener as follows.

```
@Component
public class EscalationTimerListener implements ExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    ExceptionWorkflowService exceptionWorkflowService;

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        //Process the escalated tasks here  
        this.exceptionWorkflowService.escalateWorkflowTask(execution);
    }

}
```

Now when I start my tomcat server activiti framework internally calls the listener even before my entire spring context is loaded. Hence exceptionWorkflowService is null (since spring hasn't inejcted it yet!) and my code breaks.

Note : this scenario only occurs if my server isn't running at the escalation time of tasks and I start/restart my server post this time. If my server is already running during escalation time then the process runs smoothly. Because when server started it had injected the service and my listener has triggered later.

I have tried delaying activiti configuration using `@DependsOn` annotation so that it loads after ExceptionWorkflowService is initialized as below.

```
@Bean
    @DependsOn({ "dataSource", "transactionManager","exceptionWorkflowService" })
    public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        final SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
        config.setAsyncExecutorActivate(true);
        config.setJobExecutorActivate(true);
        config.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        config.setTransactionManager(this.transactionManager);
        config.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(this.schemaUpdate);
        config.setHistory(this.history);
        config.setTransactionsExternallyManaged(this.transactionsExternallyManaged);
        config.setDatabaseType(this.dbType);

        // Async Job Executor
        final DefaultAsyncJobExecutor asyncExecutor = new DefaultAsyncJobExecutor();
        asyncExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        asyncExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        asyncExecutor.setQueueSize(100);
        config.setAsyncExecutor(asyncExecutor);

        return config;
    }
```

But this gives circular reference error.

I have also tried adding a bean to `SpringProcessEngineConfiguration` as below.

```
Map<Object, Object> beanObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
beanObjectMap.put("exceptionWorkflowService", new ExceptionWorkflowServiceImpl());
config.setBeans(beanObjectMap);
```

and the access the same in my listener as :

```
Map<Object, Object> registeredBeans = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getBeans();
ExceptionWorkflowService exceptionWorkflowService = (ExceptionWorkflowService) registeredBeans.get("exceptionWorkflowService");
exceptionWorkflowService.escalateWorkflowTask(execution);
```

This works **but** my repository has been autowired into my service which hasn't been initialized yet! So it again throws error in service layer :)

**So is there a way that I can trigger escalation listeners only after my entire spring context is loaded?**

Comment: is `ExceptionWorkflowService` annotated as `@Component`?

Comment: No @Abbas ! But its implementation ExceptionWorkflowServiceImpl is marked with @Service("exceptionWorkflowService")

Comment: instead of extending `EscalationTimerListener` to `ExecutionListener`. have you tried making i a bean and calling the class from `delegate expression`?. at least that should work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the class to ApplicationListener?
Not sure if it will work, but equally I'm not sure why your listener code is actually being executed on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the implementation type of listeners using Java class or delegate expression and then in the class implement JavaDelegate instead of ExecutionListener.